# How to wipe RAM on shutdown (prevent Cold Boot Attacks)?

Tags: encryption, disk, ram

My system is encrypted using Full Disk Encryption, i.e. everything except /boot is encrypted using dmcrypt/luks. I am concerned about [Cold Boot Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack).

Prior work:

- https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/memory_erasure/
- http://tails.boum.org/forum/Ram_Wipe_Script/
- http://dee.su/liberte-security
- http://forum.dee.su/topic/stand-alone-implementation-of-your-ram-wipe-scripts

Can you please provide instructions on how to wipe the RAM once Ubuntu is shutdown/restarted?

Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`sdmem`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man1/sdmem.1.html).

```
sudo apt-get install secure-delete
```

To make it run at every shutdown, we'll create an Upstart job file called memory_wipe.conf.

*Note: this is **one** command. Copy/paste it in its entirety!*

```
echo '# upstart config - wipes memory on shutdown

description  "Wipes memory on shutdown"

start on (runlevel [016] and stopped gdm)

script
    sdmem
end script' > sudo tee /etc/init/memory_wipe.conf
```

Restart your computer and upon the next reboot, your RAM will be wiped securely!

Comment: Isn't kexec into a new kernel required?
Otherwise the old kernel does not get overwritten?

Comment: Wiping the RAM when gdm stops might be a bad idea, since it causes an unclean shutdown?
sdmem might overwrite itself or the kernel, therefore crashing the system without wiping the complete the RAM?

Comment: Why are the implementations in the Live CD's (prior work) so complex and these so simple? Too simple to be safe?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1500936

If you still want to do it then:

> Look for secure-delete in Synaptic
>
> The Secure-Delete package comes with four commands:
>
> > srm - Secure remove; used for deleting files or directories currently on your hard disk;
> >
> > smem - Secure memory wiper; used to wipe traces of data from your computer's memory (RAM);
> >
> > sfill - Secure free space wiper; used to wipe all traces of data from the free space on your disk;
> >
> > sswap - Secure swap wiper; used to wipe all traces of data from your swap partition.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1008111

And to make it run when you want:

> To execute a script upon rebooting Ubuntu
>
> > Put your script in /etc/rc0.d
> >     Make it executable (sudo chmod +x myscript)
> >     Note: The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order
> >
> > The name of your script must begin with K99 to run at the right time. 
> >     To execute a script at shutdown
> >
> > Put your script in /etc/rc6.d
> >     Make it executable (sudo chmod +x myscript)
> >     Note: The scripts in this directory are executed in alphabetical order
> >
> > The name of your script must begin with K99 to run at the right time.

Source: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3348-ubuntu-executing-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown

If you do not know how to make a script:

> Make a text file in an easy to find directory:
>
> Code:
>
> > `#!/bin/bash`
> >
> > COMMAND1
> >
> > COMMAND2
> >
> > COMMAND3`
>
> Use the shebang line that I have given. Replace COMMAND1 and etc with the command you would like the script to run.
>
> Save the text file and then you have to make it executable. For this I will assume that the the file is called "test.sh". To make it executable:
>
> > chmod 775 test.sh
>
> Then you can run the script:
>
> > ./test.sh

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=928839

Hope this helps,

Leinardo

Comment: Why use the deprecated rc runlevel system?

Comment: I don't think this can work. Unless kexec into a fresh kernel with smem, the old kernel may overwrite itself or smem and not everything is cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need it if you are not using `DDR2` or older `RAM`s. [Here](http://static.usenix.org/event/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman.pdf) and [here](http://www1.cs.fau.de/filepool/projects/coldboot/fares_coldboot.pdf) are resources that confirm `DDR3` looses voltage to fast to be susceptible to `Cold Boot Attack (CBA)`s.

Comment: Your first link (by Halderman et al.) doesn't mention DDR3 at all. The presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHq2xG4XJXM says that a cold boot attack is viable against DDR3.