# Prevent cold boot attack on running laptop by overwriting ram

Tags: boot, vector

Prevent cold boot attack on running laptop by overwriting ram

Id like to use my laptop as a recording device when i leave home, but there would still be the possibiltity for a cold boot attack or with ddr3ram even warm boot attack is possible as i have read. Could one overwrite RAM before leaving the laptop locked and make cold boot inposssible that way?

I found this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/sdmem.1.html

will sdmem really overwrite the RAM of a running system? If so could you write me a script that does this everytime i lock my pc?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/538/

Comment: Physical access == root access you have to limit / prevent physical access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried the DEA might be sniffing your RAM when you're away from the *house* take a look at [TRESOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRESOR).

The [TRESOR Readme](https://www1.cs.fau.de/tresor?q=content/readme) should have enough information about patching a kernel for you to be in business.

[TRESOR Runs Encryption Securely Outside RAM](https://www1.cs.fau.de/tresor)

Another option along the lines of the question is the duplicate

[How to wipe RAM on shutdown (prevent Cold Boot Attacks)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153245/how-to-wipe-ram-on-shutdown-prevent-cold-boot-attacks)

Comment: I have tried to implement your second link but the lightdm.conf files is missing in Ubuntu 14.04 so i don#t know where to paste the line session-cleanup-script=/path/to/scrip.