# Securely wipe RAM before shutdown

Tags: 14.04, security, ram, secure-erase

I want my machine to wipe RAM before every shutdown, so I can prevent cold-boot attacks. I read [How to wipe RAM on shutdown (prevent Cold Boot Attacks)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153245/how-to-wipe-ram-on-shutdown-prevent-cold-boot-attacks), but I don't know at which version of Ubuntu can that script works, and there is some talk that it could overwrite kernel and break system.

So does anybody know how to do this on 14.04?

Comment: According to the [Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sdmem.1.html), it works on Ubuntu 2.04 LTS, 
14.04 LTS, 15.10, and 16.04.

Comment: RAM wipes itself when power is removed.

Comment: You realize a cold boot attack bypasses the OS shutdown, so there's no way to use an OS shutdown script to avoid it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, but not immediately

Comment: @StephenM.Webb I thought only some better crafted cold-boots can bypass it, are you sure that all can do it?